# How to disable/hide JavaFx WebViewer address bar?

Tags: webview, javafx

Is it possible to disable or hide the address bar on JavaFX webviewr? I"m running a javascript application and there is no need to display an address bar. Thanks!

Hank

Answer (score 1):

A JavaFX WebView doesn't have an address bar.

Comment: Hmm... the examples i've been working with does. But maybe its more of an add on feature. Thanks anyways